# Storing UTC timestamp to database using JPA

Tags: java, sql, database, jpa, timestamp

Having following table (vendor makes no difference - I personally tried Oracle and PgSQL):

```
CREATE TABLE times (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  time TIMESTAMP
);
```

and JPA Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "times")
public class TimeEntity {

    @Id
    @Column
    public Long id;

    ???
    public ??? time;
}
```

**Is there a way how to finish the entity in a way, which would store the datetime value as UTC timestamp?** Eg. the same value which is returned by `java.util.Date.getTime()` method.

I've already tried `Calendar` with different timezones, both `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date`, `Timestamp`, different Temporal types but with no success whatsoever. Tried on WebSphere and Spring + Hibernate + Tomcat, with Oracle and PostgreSQL (just out of curiosity).

Its value always ends up shifted to the default Timezone of the server.
Values checked in the DB in following way: `select (extract(epoch from time)) from times;`

The only way I found to store the value as UTC is using just JDBC and PreparedStatement. But this is not really an option as we are integrating big EJB/JPA based app into existing infrastructure, existing database and applications spread across three different timezones. Thats why we need the UTC timestamp value as described.

Is it really such an impossible task or did we miss something obvious? I kind of hope the later.

**EDIT, EXAMPLE:**

The stored value for all implementations I tried so far is at this moment: **1462017276 (Sat, 30 Apr 2016 11:54:36)**, which is our current time here in Sydney.

I need it to be **1461981275 (Sat, 30 Apr 2016 01:54:35)**, as given by Date.getTime().

Comment: After spending another few hours on this, it really seems that except for setting the servers to the UTC timezones, there is no other generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

TIMESTAMP in Oracle does not support time zones.

You should consider using:

```
TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE Datatype
TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE Datatype
```

More info:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006081
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006169

Comment: Hey,  thanks, but that's what I want! I don't want to have any tz. I need t have the millis since the epoch - UTC timestamp.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding the problem. If you only use the value to store and retrieve epoch, why not convert the date to long in java in desired timezone and store long value in db?

Comment: good question ... because the db is already in place and its used by few other apps and changing the data type is not possible. Actually using TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE could fix my problem, but then the other apps start to fail.

Comment: I also tried to use the numeric types in the java Entity, but it does not work at all with the TIMESTAMP column.

Answer (score -1):

i think using these annotations resolve the issue 
    @Column(name = "DATETIME_FIELD")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private java.util.Calendar time;

Comment: http://www.developerscrappad.com/228/java/java-ee/ejb3-jpa-dealing-with-date-time-and-timestamp/

Comment: I came across that article few times, but its the same, tried for two Calendar instances - (UTC and my Default - Sydney+10). The stored value at this moment is for both instances 1462017276 (Sat, 30 Apr 2016 11:54:36), which is our current time here in Sydney. I need it to be 1461981275 (Sat, 30 Apr 2016 01:54:35), as given by Date.getTime().